# How to show list in fragment on back pressed from next fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, onbackpressed

I have `MyTrips fragment` which contains `ViewPager`. So it contains two tabs i.e two fragments one is `ScheduleListFrgment` and another is `TripHistoryFragment`.

Now As I replace `MyTrips fragment` it first shows `ScheduleListFragment`, loads data from server and shows in a list, it also loads data of tripHistory from server.

So now I have given click event to the list item of `ScheduleListFragment` so `onClick` it replaces `ScheduleListFragment` with `PostDetailsFragment`.

Now after I press back from `PostDetailsFragment` it shows empty `ScheduleListFragment` with no list.

I want to show the list when user press from from `PostDetailsFragment`.

**`ScheduleListFragment`**

```
public class ScheduledTravelFragment extends Fragment implements GetScheduledTripsAsyncTask.GetScheduleTripsCallBack{

    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView_list;
    private ArrayList<Trips> mTripsList;
    private ScheduledTravelAdapter mTripsAdapter;
    public TextView mTextViewData;
    private String mDateTime;
    private SessionData sessionData;

    private RelativeLayout parentLayout;

    public ScheduledTravelFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scheduled_travel, container, false);


        setUpUI(view);


        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        GetScheduledTripsAsyncTask getScheduledTripsAsyncTask = new GetScheduledTripsAsyncTask(getActivity(),parentLayout,ScheduledTravelFragment.this,ScheduledTravelFragment.this);
        getScheduledTripsAsyncTask.execute(mDateTime,sessionData.getString("api_key",""));
    }

    public void setUpUI(View view)
    {

        mRecyclerView_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_tripList);
        mTextViewData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
        parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parentPanel);

        mTripsList = new ArrayList<Trips>();
        mTripsAdapter = new ScheduledTravelAdapter(getActivity(),mTripsList, ScheduledTravelFragment.this);
        mRecyclerView_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView_list.setAdapter(mTripsAdapter);
        mRecyclerView_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView_list.setItemViewCacheSize(50);
        mRecyclerView_list.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mRecyclerView_list.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

        sessionData = new SessionData(getActivity());
        mDateTime = String.valueOf(CommonUtils.getCurrentDateTime());

    }

    @Override
    public void doPostExecute(ArrayList<Trips> list)
    {
        mTripsList.addAll(list);

        mTripsAdapter.notifyDataChanged();

    }


}
```

**`ScheduleListAdapter`**

```
public class ScheduledTravelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Trips> list;
    private ScheduledTravelFragment tripListFragment;
    static final int TYPE_LOAD_TRIP = 0, TYPE_LOAD_PROGRESS = 1;
    boolean isLoading = false, isMoreDataAvailable = true;
    TransportListAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener;

    public ScheduledTravelAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Trips> list,ScheduledTravelFragment tripListFragment) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.tripListFragment = tripListFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        switch (viewType) {

            case TYPE_LOAD_TRIP:
                View v_order_header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trip_layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TripsHolder(v_order_header);
                break;

        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (position >= getItemCount() - 1 && isMoreDataAvailable && !isLoading && loadMoreListener != null) {
            isLoading = true;
            loadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
        }

        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_LOAD_TRIP) {
            TripsHolder tripsHolder = (TripsHolder) holder;
            retriveAllTrips(tripsHolder, position);
        } else {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Object obj = list.get(position);

        if (obj instanceof Transport) {
            return TYPE_LOAD_TRIP;
        }

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    public void retriveAllTrips(final TripsHolder holder, int position) {


        final Trips data = (Trips) list.get(position);

        final String newDate = CommonUtils.formateDateFromstring("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd MMM, yyyy", data.getmDate());


        holder.tv_date.setText(newDate);
        holder.tv_from.setText(data.getmFrom());
        holder.tv_to.setText(data.getmTo());

        //go to post detail fragment

            holder.lay_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("pt_id", data.getmPostId());
                    bundle.putString("pt_name", data.getmPostName());
                    bundle.putString("pt_details", data.getmPostDetails());
                    bundle.putString("pt_photo", data.getmImage());
                    bundle.putString("pt_date", data.getmDate());
                    bundle.putString("from", data.getmFrom());
                    bundle.putString("to", data.getmTo());

                    //go to post details screen
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = tripListFragment.getFragmentManager();
                    PostDetailsFragment fragment = new PostDetailsFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, fragment, "POST_DETAILS_FRAGMENT").addToBackStack("O").commit();

                }
            });

 }
    public void notifyDataChanged() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        isLoading = false;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

MyTrips frgament:

```
public class MyTripsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private CharSequence Titles[]={"Scheduled Travel","Travel History"};
    private int Numboftabs =2;
    private SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_trips, container, false);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ImageView mLogo = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
        mLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        title.setText(R.string.myTrips);

        mAdapter =  new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ScheduledTravelFragment(), "Scheduled Travel");
        adapter.addFragment(new TravelHistoryFragment(), "Travel History");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

At first time when fragment created title is mytrips.

[image]

on next fragment changing text.`

final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

```
    ImageView mLogo = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
    mLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
    title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    title.setText(R.string.tripDetails);`
```

OnBackpress of next fragment. Carry app logo is set on main fragment that i visible.

[image]

Comment: you can do either of two things start your Async task from onResume so that when you come back onbackPress you can fetch data and second if you don't want to fetch everytime you come to the fragment save the list data when you fetch it for first time and then use that data when you come back

Comment: I tried to call the async task onResume of a fragment but it was still blank.@sumit

Comment: oh you're initializing your adaptor from oncreate initialize it from onResume

Comment: on/resume is not called onBackPressed. @sumit

Comment: override all method and check which method is getting called onBackPressed

Comment: Add All your fragments on back stack, As Smartiz suggest.it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use replace. For your purpose try add.

```
fragmentManager
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.mycontainer, fragment, "POST_DETAILS_FRAGMENT")
.addToBackStack("O")
.commit();
```

This way your last fragment remain at its state won't change and won't create again.

Don't forget to make your next fragment root layout clickable. This way, if you click anywhere, it won't click the bottom fragment.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Also don't forget to give background to your next fragment

Comment: add dose not work fine it overlapped the previous fragment all design looks messed up.

Comment: but I as I have added the title on MyTrips fragment and changing it on next added fragment, on Back pressed it shows Main fragments title, not of mytrips title.

Comment: Edit your question please and add two screenshot. @Sid

Comment: Dear @Sid , please put the code related to changing title in on back pressed of the second fragment. It will fix your problem completely.
there is also another way. tell me if it didn't solve your problem, I edit my answer and share the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use PostDetailsFragment as the child of ScheduleListFrgment.
This bug will never arise.

getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction() and further step.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all of this inside onResume:

```
GetScheduledTripsAsyncTask getScheduledTripsAsyncTask = new GetScheduledTripsAsyncTask(getActivity(),parentLayout,ScheduledTravelFragment.this,ScheduledTravelFragment.this);
        getScheduledTripsAsyncTask.execute(mDateTime,sessionData.getString("api_key",""));

mTripsList = new ArrayList<Trips>();
        mTripsAdapter = new ScheduledTravelAdapter(getActivity(),mTripsList, ScheduledTravelFragment.this);
        mRecyclerView_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView_list.setAdapter(mTripsAdapter);
        mRecyclerView_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView_list.setItemViewCacheSize(50);
        mRecyclerView_list.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mRecyclerView_list.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

        sessionData = new SessionData(getActivity());
        mDateTime = String.valueOf(CommonUtils.getCurrentDateTime());
```

Comment: I tried to put breakpoint in onResume() but it did not get called onBackPressed